# If $X$ measurable on $\Omega \times [0,1]$ can we approximate $f$ by simple function?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ a stochastic process (on ($\Omega\times [0,\infty ),\mathcal F\otimes \mathcal B([0,\infty ),\mathbb P\otimes \lambda )$ where $\mathcal B([0,\infty ))$ denote the Borel $\sigma -$algebra of $[0,\infty )$ and $\lambda $ the Lebesgue measure).

- I know that if $f:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is measurable on a measurable space $(\Omega ,\mathcal M,\mu)$, then, there is an increasing sequence $(\varphi _n)$ of simple function s.t. $\varphi _n(x)\nearrow f(x)$ for all $x\in \Omega $.
- I don't know how to apply that to $X$. So :

**Q1)** Is there a sequence of simple function $X_n:\Omega \times [0,\infty )$ s.t. $X_n\nearrow X$ ?

**Q2)** Is there a sequence of simple function $X_n^t:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $X_n^t\nearrow X_t$ ?

**Q3)** Is there a sequence of simple function $X_n^\omega :[0,\infty )\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $X_n^\omega \nearrow X_{\cdot }(\omega )$ ?

I don't really see how to adapt this theorem in the case of a stochastic process.

Comment: I'm confused what the issue is. First of all, you shouldn't use $X$ in the first bullet; it's confusing given that you use $X$ in another way. But in any event, can't you just use that first bullet with $\Omega\times[0,\infty)$? What's the issue?

Comment: @m: you right, thanks. For your last comment, I guess I can, but does the way I did it works ?

Comment: I have no idea what "the way you did it" was. You just said you don't know how to do it and then asked a question. I don't know what you want from me.

Comment: @mathworker21: just say if $Q1),Q2)$ and Q3)$ are correct or not :)

Comment: (I edited... I wanted to say : sequence of simple functions)

Comment: $X$ is measurable on $\Omega\times[0,\infty)$, right? If so, then yes to Q1. Also $Q2,Q3$ seem like yes. I don't know if you are asking a trick question. The first bullet literally says you can approximate a measurable function by simple functions. And then you're asking three times if a measurable function can be approximated by simple functions. Am I missing something?

Comment: No you didn't, thank you very much. :)